# Possible differences from production and developer in terms of SOQL processing

Tags: apex, soql, batch, method

I've created a batch process in my developer account. All is working well and then, I've created a package for it and put in inside my production account. There, I found out that my batch process won't run properly. To explain further, below is my sample code.

```
public with sharing class myBatch implements Database.batchable<AggregateResult>, Database.Stateful
{
    public String THEID;

    public myBatch() {
    }

    public Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.batchableContext batchableContext) { 
        return [select Primary_Adviser__c a, SUM(total__c) total from Account where Primary_Adviser__c != null group by Primary_Adviser__c];
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<AggregateResult> scope)  {
        Map<Id, Decimal> m = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
        List<Account> finalAcc = new List<Account>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : scope) {
            Account acc = new Account();

            acc.Id  = (Id) ar.get('a');
            acc.finalTotal__c = Double.valueOf(ar.get('total'));
            acc.total_Last_Updated_Date__c = System.now();
            finalAcc.add(acc); 

        }
        Update finalAcc;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    }

}
```

I'm really confuse because when I view the debug log(production), the `start` function for batch returns 0 row. But when I try to run the query in developer console it return many rows. BTW, I call this batch in the `finish` function from another batch. But as I've said, all is working well in my developer account. FUrthermore I also have a simple query in my developer which is working well(below code).

```
[SELECT Id,Primary_Adviser__c FROM Account WHERE Primary_Adviser__c =:THEID]
```

The problem is that , In my production it will also return 0 result. What are the possible reason for this problems ? Please help.

Comment: Have you confirmed that in production there are Account rows with `Primary_Adviser__c != null` as you have that check in the where clause?

Comment: @KeithC Yes. Actually this is the code you've given to me yesterday. And the weird thing is that, when I run the query in the developer console, All the data will be displayed.

Comment: How many Account records come back in production when `Primary_Adviser__c != null`? There might be a [selectivity problem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm). Particularly with using a negative operator (!=).

Comment: @DanielBallinger It doesn't even exceed 100 records.  What is the problem with using (!=) operator?

Comment: @Hope. The linked article covers the selectivity problems with `!=`. However, with only 100 records it sounds more like a permissions issue for the use that started the batch job. Can they user account that is running the batch access to records in question?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I'm not sure if it is about permission. But there are batch job that I can run there are just few batch that dont run but not all . Does class versioning matters in the system processes?

Comment: Please post the code you use in the finish method of the other batch that constructs and executes this batch. Also, post the relevant portion of the debug log where the start query is executed (a few lines above and below it as well). Also, what does the "THEID" do in your batch as I do not see it being used

Comment: Most probably you are using hardcoded Id which doesn't exist in production.